# how to write cross joins like (+) operator in query dsl

Tags: querydsl

jpaQuery.from(tableA,tableb). (how to write the below condition) in query dsl
tableA.id = tableb.id(+)

Can you give an example for

JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(em);

QTableA tableA = QTableA.tableA;
QTableB tableB = QTableB.tableB

query.from(tableA ,tableB).where(tableA.id.eq(tableB.id)).
singleResult(tableB.name);

The above query i have written  join how to write LEFT OUTER JOIN

Can you please help me Thanks!

Comment: Please add tag "jpa" to your query.

Comment: I have modified the tag can you please help me how to write this type of conditions (tableA.id = tableB.id(+))

Comment: why would he need JPA when the question is NOT JPA API. QueryDSL has its own API, and supports many underlying technologies. Nowhere in his question is JPA mentioned!

Comment: I have updated question what i want. Can you please look it once Thanks!